# Is there a way of merging in Stata when the keys might be mixed in different variables?

Tags: merge, stata, panel-data

I am trying to `merge 1:1` two datasets, which correspond to surveys of the same individuals at different periods; no unique identifier was constructed.

What was gathered was email addresses, although those are stored in three different variables in each dataset. People did not necessarily write the same address in each.

Does anyone know how or if such thing can be done?

```
clear
set more off

input str16 mai1 str16 email2   str16 email3         str16 data1
"jhon@foo.com"  "jhon@foo.com"  "jhonnie@foofoo.net" "aaaa1"
"bob@foo.net"   ""              "bob@foo.net"        "bbbb1"
end

tempfile first
save "`first'"

clear

input str16 mai1    str16 email2    str16 email3   str16 data1
""                  "bob@foo.net"   ""      ""     "bbbb2"
"jhonnie@foo.net"   ""              ""             "aaaa2"
end
```

Comment: Do you know why each participant did not necessarily write the same email in all surveys? Is it due to typos, or another reason? It sounds like you might need to use some sort of approximate/fuzzy string matching to determine the "correct" email, which can then be used as the unique identifier. A quick Google of `approximate string matching stata` yields some resources that could be helpful.

Comment: Hello, I do not know why they did that. My guess is that since it was a survey at a university, they might have been using both their universities and personal emails depending on whether they expected to get some feedback or follow up. But this is just a guess.  I will look into this approximate string matching, thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

A way to get started is to hold an election among the three addresses for each individual in each dataset:

If you sort on the addresses for each individual, then after sorting

1. If all email addresses agree, the 2nd will be the same as all.
2. If two email addresses agree, the 2nd will be that agreed address, because those two will sort last or first, depending on the alphabet, but either way one of the two will be second. (The principle is like the median of 3 numbers: with cases either like 1, 1, 2 or like 1, 2, 2, if any 2 numbers agree out of 3, that number is the median; so also with strings sorted alphanumerically.)
3. If three email addresses disagree, the 2nd will be no worse as a guess than any other.
4. If one email address is blank, and the others disagree, the same applies.
5. If two email addresses are blank, use the one that was given.
6. If all are blank, goodness knows.

If you do this in both datasets, and  `merge 1:1` on the results, then look at what doesn't match after the `merge` and consider your options. There is a choice ranging from abandoning what doesn't match to  trying something else.

```
clear 
input str16 mai1 str16 email2   str16 email3         str16 data1
"jhon@foo.com"  "jhon@foo.com"  "jhonnie@foofoo.net" "aaaa1"
"bob@foo.net"   ""              "bob@foo.net"        "bbbb1"
end

gen long id = _n 

rename mai1 email1 
reshape long email , i(id) j(which)
bysort id (email) : gen EMAIL = email[2]
replace EMAIL = email[3] if EMAIL == "" 

reshape wide email, i(id) j(which)

list 

     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id         email1         email2             email3   data1          EMAIL |
     |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1   jhon@foo.com   jhon@foo.com   jhonnie@foofoo.n   aaaa1   jhon@foo.com |
  2. |  2    bob@foo.net                       bob@foo.net   bbbb1    bob@foo.net |
     +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

.

You can extend this technique to find second and at worst third guesses in each case.

This technique will catch 1 of 2 cases in your data example, but careful study will find the second match.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the code.
I will try the method as soon as possible.

An alternative approach that I was thinking of going sequentially through the nine possible combinations in both datasets doing 1:1 merges, and using the non-matched observations for the next combination.